# How to shuffle words in a sentence and show them with spacing on a UILabel?

Tags: swift, xcode, shuffle

```
        let mySentences:String = "Hello. nice to meet you!"
        let divideMySentencesAndShuffled:[String] = mySentences.components(separatedBy: " ").shuffled()

        showSentence.text = divideMySentencesAndShuffled.joined()
```

I tried the above code, but the result is like this : Hello.you!nicemeetto

I'd like to give spaces to the shuffled sentence. Like, nice to Hello! you. meet

Comment: Is `.joined(separator: " ")` what you are after?

Comment: Id recommend renaming `mySentences` to something like `inputText`. Because it's entirely possible that `mySentences` contains text that doesn't form a sentence, or only a singular sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a space as a separator:

```
divideMySentencesAndShuffled.joined(separator: " ")
```

However, I would recommend some other changes. Often times, there are situations in which you have long expressions that would benefit from being broken down into sub-expressions assigned to well-named intermediate variables. The variable names act like comments, to explain what each sub-expression is.

However, this is a case in which the intermediate variable doesn't add much value, because you wouldn't really know what `divideMySentences` means if you didn't look at the right side's value. Explaining that division means splitting text into words (well not quite, because splitting on spaces still leaves punctuation attached to the words, but close enough) would make the variable name longer and more complex than the actual code itself.  At that point, it's better to just skip the intermediate variable. To improve clarity however, you can make the chained method calls be one per line.

Also, don't add type annotations where they don't add value.

Compare:

```
let mySentences: String = "Hello. nice to meet you!"
let dividedMySentences:[String] = mySentences.components(separatedBy: " ")
let dividedMySentencesAndShuffled:[String] = dividedMySentences.shuffled()
let result: String = divideMySentencesAndShuffled.joined(separator: " ")
```

To:

```
let inputText = "Hello. nice to meet you!"
let scrambledWords = inputText
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
    .shuffled()
    .joined(separator: " ")
```

You don't even have to comment what the `components(separatedBy:)`, `shuffled()`, `joined(separator:)` calls do, because they already read pretty much like plain English. This is what people refer to as "self documenting" code.

It's generally preferable to write self-documenting code where possible like this, rather than having complex code explained by English comments, because comments can easily go out-of-sync from the code they comment on.

Comment: Why shouldn't one introduce immediate variables? OP's code might not be the best currently, but I feel like the intent of the code is much clearer if `divideMySentencesAndShuffled` in OP's code is renamed to `shuffledWords`.

Comment: `divideMySentencesAndShuffled` is only clear because you're looking at the rhs of the assignment to understand precisely what "dividing" means, and what's being shuffled. If you didn't have those details, I don't think you would have picked up on them from the name. So then it stands to reason, that this particular intermediate variable doesn't add value, since you need to look at its value to understand it, so just skip it and get to the point. There are certainly times when you should break down large expressions into well-named sub-expressions, but I don't think this is one of those.

Comment: @Sweeper I can see my answer wasn't very clear on this, and it might read as too-general of a claim. I'll edit it.